# transform_keys for an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, key, transform

I have the following array of hashes and I want to use transform_keys to strip the beginning of each key using a regex:

```
array_of_hashes = [{"a_0_abc"=>"1",  
  "a_0_def"=>"1",  
  "a_0_hij"=>"1",},  
 {"a_1_abc”=>"2",  
  "a_1_def"=>"2",  
  "a_1_hij"=>"2"}]
```

and I want the following:

```
transformed_hash_keys = [{"abc"=>"1",  
 "def"=>"1",  
 "hij"=>"1",},  
{"abc"=>"2",  
 "def"=>"2",  
 "hij"=>"2"}]
```

I have the following method but it results in array_of_hashes instead of transformed_hash_keys:

```
def strip  
    s = array_of_hashes.each { |hash| hash.transform_keys { |key| key.sub(/^a_(\d+)_/, '') } }  
end
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform_keys` doesn't operate in place and `each` returns the original iterator, not the result of the block.

You could do what you want with `map` instead of `each`.

```
def strip  
    s = array_of_hashes.map { |hash| hash.transform_keys { |key| key.sub(/^a_(\d+)_/, '') } }  
end
```

Or, you could use `transform_keys!` to modify the contents of `array_of_hashes`

```
def strip  
    s = array_of_hashes.each { |hash| hash.transform_keys! { |key| key.sub(/^a_(\d+)_/, '') } }  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure Ruby solution.

```
arr = [{ "a_0_abc"=>"1", "a_0_def"=>"1", "a_0_hij"=>"1" },
       { "a_1_abc"=>"2", "a_1_def"=>"2", "a_1_hij"=>"2" }]

arr.map { |h| h.map { |k,v| [k[/[[:alpha:]]+\z/], v] }.to_h }
  #=> [{"abc"=>"1", "def"=>"1", "hij"=>"1"}, {"abc"=>"2", "def"=>"2", "hij"=>"2"}]
```

or

```
arr.map { |h| h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[k[/[[:alpha:]]+\z/]] = v } }
  # => [{"abc"=>"1", "def"=>"1", "hij"=>"1"}, {"abc"=>"2", "def"=>"2", "hij"=>"2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This lets you do any kind of transformation on the keys just passing a block to it:

```
def strip_keys(object)
  deep_transform_keys_in_object!(object) { |key| key.sub(/^a_(\d+)_/, '') }
end

def deep_transform_keys_in_object!(object, &block)
  case object
  when Hash
    object.keys.each do |key|
      value = object.delete(key)
      object[yield(key)] = deep_transform_keys_in_object!(value, &block)
    end
    object
  when Array
    object.map! { |e| deep_transform_keys_in_object!(e, &block) }
  else
    object
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this challenge in a recent rails project.

A quick hack which uses rails' deep_transform_keys and works with rails 4.1+ is to wrap the array in a hash:

```rb
hash = { array: array }
transformed = hash.deep_transform_keys { |key| key.sub(/^a_(\d+)_/, '') }[:array]
```

It looks a bit dirty, but it has some advantages over for instance a `case` statement:

- No need to repeat the transformer or store it in a variable
- It supports arrays in arrays, e.g. `[[{key: :value}], [{key: :value}]]`, which would otherwise require recursion.